# How to create wheel picker with specific time ? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

i want to create a "Wheel Picker " where user can select hour when the food will be delievered. The first option i want to be something like "ASAP", and the hour will be from 45 to 45 minutes. This is what i saw on internet, but i do not know how to implement this with a Wheel Picker . Can you help me out ?

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.datePickerMode = .time
    
let minDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 14, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) // 2PM
    
let maxDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 21, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) // 9PM

picker.minimumDate = minDate
picker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

Comment: You are using a UIDatePicker but have tagged the question with swiftui. So which one is it, UIKit or SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do it by hand, computing your delivery times (options) somewhere.
But it would be something like this:

```
@State private var selection = ""
var options = ["ASAP", "1pm", "1:30pm", "2pm"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Delivery time: \(selection)")
        Picker("", selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) {
                Text("\($0)")
            }
        }.pickerStyle(.inline)
    }
}
```